# How to include .go for search for Ack in VIM?

Tags: vim, go, ack

Here is my .vimrc for Ack, But it can't search .go files, I'd like add .go support.

```
let g:ackprg="ack-grep -H --nocolor --nogroup --column"

function! Ack(args)

let grepprg_bak=&grepprg
exec "set grepprg=" . g:ackprg
execute "silent! grep " . a:args
botright copen
let &grepprg=grepprg_bak
exec "redraw!"

endfunction

command! -nargs=* -complete=file Ack call Ack(<q-args>)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since version 1.94, *ack* has support for the Go language built-in.

```
$ ack --help type
...
    --[no]go           .go
```

You can explicitly enable it by passing `--go`, but it should be included in the search by default.

Comment: Thx! I used apt-get to install ack, the ack version is only v1.39. That's why. Thx again!